# Adding a new field to Post in Parse.com application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, parse-platform

//This is an update to my post from earlier today.

I want to populate a few fields within the Post dialog of Parse.com's Anywall app. With the code below I can only populate one field. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? I think the problem might be related to the `alert.setView`.

```
     // Create the builder where the new post is entered
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    alert.setTitle("Create a Bicyclist Count Post");
    final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
    final EditText inputNotes = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
    inputNotes.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setView(inputNotes);
    // Handle the dialog input
    alert.setPositiveButton("Post", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Create a post.
        AnywallPost post = new AnywallPost();
        // Set the location to the current user's location
        post.setLocation(myPoint);
        post.setText(input.getText().toString());
        post.setNotes(inputNotes.getText().toString());
```

//End update

I want to allow users to populate additional fields within the Post screen of Parse.com's example [Anywall](https://parse.com/tutorials/anywall) application. I have added the new column, bicyclistCount, within the table through my Parse.com account:
[image]

I am having trouble getting it to display in the Post screen. The area that users enter text in the image below populates the text column. Has anyone been able to add additional fields to their Post within the Anywall app? Thank you

[image]

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but I had a similar issue with an app in the past. If you manually create a new column within the Parse UI, but none of the records have a value Parse will not return that column in the data collection through the API. Try manually adding a value to one row within the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is simple technique. Try to add all your `edittext` in a `linearlayout` with `vertical` orientation then set this layout (view) to `alert dialog` for example:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alert.setTitle("Create a Bicyclist Count Post");

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = 
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        layout.setLayoutParams(params);

        final EditText input = new EditText(context);

        final EditText inputNotes = new EditText(context);

        //do your remaining stuff with input and inputNotes

        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
        inputNotes.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

        layout.addView(input);
        layout.addView(inputNotes);


        alert.setView(layout);

        alert.show();
```

Comment: This worked. I just needed to remove `alert.show();`. Thank you